# Accessing site using IP (.net)

Tags: .net, iis

I have Configured a site in IIS.
In host file I have mapped 10.10.73.98 mywebsite.com

I am able to access it using mywebsite.com

I tried to access using 10.10.73.98/mywebsite.com from IPOD It is giving error.

I want to access using my IP i.e 10.10.73.98/

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the website and add a new website as per below image
[image]

Now In your browser access it with IP

[image]

Comment: Thanks and It is working fine. But I am using webservice also I want to connect both website and service.

Comment: Ok I have done it. I am using different ports now its working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps there is a fire wall working in your server.
An easiest way is turn it off.
If you use Linux,

```
$ /etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables stop
```

you use root user, when type this command.

Comment: configure property and port (TCP). Release 80 port on Http.